# How to get a Numeric Stepper and sliders to work together in Flash CS4 AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, slider, flash-cs4, numericstepper

Hi I am working on a piece of coursework for school and I want to have a page where I have sliders that reflect a numeric stepper and vice versa however whenever I find a tutorial online it keeps giving me errors, the most recent of which is 1120: Access of undefined property NumericStepperEvent. I am hesitant to continue with the rest of the steppers because of the fact that I am unsure how to get it to work but I need to have this section done by Friday. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks Matt

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import fl.controls.Label;
import fl.controls.NumericStepper;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    //Variables
    var startPage:StartPage;
    var tutorialPage:TutorialPage;
    var maleSizePage:MaleSizePage;
    var femaleSizePage:FemaleSizePage;

    public function Main()
    {

        //Pages
        startPage = new StartPage  ;
        tutorialPage = new TutorialPage  ;
        maleSizePage = new MaleSizePage  ;
        femaleSizePage = new FemaleSizePage  ;

        addChild(startPage);

        //Event Listeners
        startPage.startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,startButtonClick);
        tutorialPage.continueButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,tutorialContinueButtonClick);
        maleSizePage.heightSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,heightSlChange_M);
        maleSizePage.neckSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,neckSlChange_M);
        maleSizePage.chestSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,chestSlChange_M);
        maleSizePage.waistSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,waistSlChange_M);
        maleSizePage.armSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,armSlChange_M);
        maleSizePage.legSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,legSlChange_M);
        maleSizePage.heightValue.addEventListener(NumericStepperEvent.CHANGE,heightVChange_M);          
    }



    function startButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        addChild(tutorialPage);
    }
    function tutorialContinueButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (startPage.maleSelection.selected == true)
        {
            addChild(maleSizePage);
            removeChild(startPage);
            removeChild(tutorialPage);
        }
        if (startPage.femaleSelection.selected == true)
        {
            addChild(femaleSizePage);
            removeChild(startPage);
            removeChild(tutorialPage);
        }
    }

    function heightSlChange_M(Event:SliderEvent):void
    {

        maleSizePage.heightValue.value = maleSizePage.heightSlider.value;
    }
    function neckSlChange_M(Event:SliderEvent):void
    {

        maleSizePage.neckValue.value = maleSizePage.neckSlider.value;

    }
    function chestSlChange_M(Event:SliderEvent):void
    {

        maleSizePage.chestValue.value = maleSizePage.chestSlider.value;

    }
    function waistSlChange_M(Event:SliderEvent):void
    {

        maleSizePage.waistValue.value = maleSizePage.waistSlider.value;
    }
    function armSlChange_M(Event:SliderEvent):void
    {

        maleSizePage.armValue.value = maleSizePage.armSlider.value;
    }
    function legSlChange_M(Event:SliderEvent):void
    {

        maleSizePage.legValue.value = maleSizePage.legSlider.value;
    }
    function heightVChange_M(Event:NumericStepper)
    {
        maleSizePage.heightSlider.value = maleSizePage.heightValue.value;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler which classes to use. At the moment it has no idea what NumericStepperEvent is.

Add at the top with other imports add:   `import mx.events.NumericStepperEvent;`

Also i'd recommend changing the argument variables written `Event:SliderEvent` to lowercase `event:SliderEvent` as this may cause another compiler error.

Comment: Ok so I did this but now I get 1172: definition fl.events.NumericStepperEvent could not be found is this a problem with my copy of flash?

Comment: @Mattyhammers My mistake, it should have been mx.events.NumericStepperEvent, answer has been changed.